# How to get a tab character?

Tags: html

In HTML, there is no character for a tab, but I am confused as to why I can copy and paste one here: "  " (You can't see the full width of it, but if you click to edit my question, you will see the character.) If I can copy and paste a tab character, there should be a unicode equivalent that can be coded into html. I know it doesn't exist, but this is a mystery I've never been able to grasp.

So my question is: why is there not a unicode character for a tab even if I can copy and paste it?

Comment: Here is a tab character for you: " ". Just text me if you need other characters! I have spaces, dashes and Greek letters as well!

Comment: On Unix: Ctrl+Shift+U and then 9 for indent character.

Comment: StackOverflow munges comment text more severely than questions or answers. ` `, ' ', and " " _were_ pasted TAB characters, quoted various ways.

Answer (score 235, accepted):

Sure there's an entity for tabs:

```
&#9;
```

(The tab is ASCII character 9, or Unicode U+0009.)

However, just like literal tabs (ones you type in to your text editor), [all tab characters are treated as whitespace by HTML parsers and collapsed into a single space](https://web.archive.org/web/20120213191501/http://www-sul.stanford.edu/tools/tutorials/html2.0/whitespace.html) except those within a [`<pre>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/pre) block, where literal tabs will be rendered as [8 spaces](http://jsfiddle.net/josh3736/HMWCq/) in a monospace font.

Comment: That's interesting, but if it is a unicode character, then html shouldn't be changing it (collapsing it) at all, should it?

Comment: Unicode doesn't have its own tab character; U+0009 is the same as the tab character you get by pressing `Tab`.  (I think you might be confusing HTML entities with the Unicode character set.)

Comment: more generally you can use &#9; in any element with CSS style white-space:pre; like in http://jsfiddle.net/cancerbero_sgx/sp269/3/

Comment: &#9; is not working in markdown file, fyi

Answer (score 154):

Try `&emsp;`

as per the docs :

> The character entities `&ensp;` and `&emsp;` denote an en space and an em
>   space respectively, where an en space is half the point size and an em
>   space is equal to the point size of the current font. For fixed pitch
>   fonts, the user agent can treat the en space as being equivalent to A
>   space character, and the em space as being equuivalent to two space
>   characters.

Docs link : https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/specialchars.html

Answer (score 62):

put it in between `<pre></pre>` tags then use this characters `&#9;`

it would not work without the `<pre></pre>` tags

Comment: Okay, this is great, I was trying to use `&#9;` by itself, but it didn't work. Thanks for mentioning `<pre>`!

Comment: Excellent suggestion. Why exactly does it behave like this?

Comment: the <pre> tag defines preformatted text any text place inside the tag will preserve spaces, line breaks, tab etc.  It usually will be displayed in a fixed width font type like Courier

Comment: You can use any html tag with combination of `white-space: pre-wrap;` or `white-space: pre;`

Answer (score 22):

Posting another alternative to be more complete.  When I tried the "pre" based answers, they added extra vertical line breaks as well.

Each tab can be converted to a sequence non-breaking spaces which require no wrapping.

```
"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"
```

This is not recommended for repeated/extensive use within a page.  A div margin/padding approach would appear much cleaner.

Comment: If tabs are being used as a tool for aligning the text to the right of the tabs (where the non-fixed width font text on the left are not equal), converting to nbsp chars won't solve the problem.

Answer (score 7):

I use `<span style="display: inline-block; width: 2ch;">&#9;</span>` for a two characters wide tab.

Comment: This isn't the same as tabs, it's just adding white space so there's no columns with this.

Answer (score 2):

Tab is [HT], or character number 9, in the unicode library.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, for efficiency reasons sequential spaces are consolidated into one space the browser actually displays. Remember what the ML in HTML stand for. It's a Mark-up Language, designed to control how text is displayed.. not whitespace :p

Still, you can pretend the browser respects tabs since all the TAB does is prepend 4 spaces, and that's easy with CSS.  either in line like ...

```
 <div style="padding-left:4.00em;">Indenented text </div>
```

Or as a regular class in a style sheet

```
.tabbed {padding-left:4.00em;}
```

Then the HTML might look like

```
<p>regular paragraph regular paragraph regular paragraph</p>
<p class="tabbed">Indented text Indented text Indented text</p>
<p>regular paragraph regular paragraph regular paragraph</p>
```

Comment: That's not what a tab does.  Tabs line up content, -- on one row it might add 3 spaces and on another 4.  Conceptually, it moves the cursor to the next tab stop.