# Insert tab into html

Tags: html, excel

I know this has been asked several times. I followed these links also

1. [HTML: Tab space instead of multiple non-breaking spaces ("nbsp")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571648/html-tab-space-instead-of-multiple-non-breaking-spaces-nbsp)
2. [How to get a tab character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9660987/how-to-get-a-tab-character)

But non of them give me the method I want. When I use above ones it give me correct result in HTML page. But the problem is I have to export that data to a excel sheet. So when I'm exporting that data I want to get them in different cells.

For example

```
<td>
    <strong>Name</strong> User Name
</td>
```

In here I want to print those in different cells (same row). If I use `</br>` it will goes to next row correctly. I couldn't find way to go to next cell.

Comment: You will have to put them into separate `<td>` cells. Tabs and line breaks (`<br/>`) only affect the rendered output, not how the data is treated when imported to Excel.

Comment: I used that. But not work as my way. Anyway thank you

Answer (score 1):

To get the Name and username in different cells, you should `<td>` both.Try t

```
<tr>
    <td><strong>Name</strong></td><td>User Name</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I used that. But not work as my way. Anyway thank you.

Comment: @Foxa In that case you will need to explain *your way*.