# html equivalent of backslash t (tab) in c#

Tags: c#, html, escaping

I'm trying to get the same behavior as a `\t` in html. How can I get that?

Like when I have `\r\n`,  I'm using `<br/>`. What about `\t`?

Thanks,

Mike.

Comment: Possibly answered here already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9660987/how-to-get-a-tab-character

Comment: There is no concept of tabs in html. Use [css or tables](http://webdesign.about.com/od/intermediatetutorials/qt/tiphtmltab.htm) for column layout.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML: Tab space instead of multiple non-breaking spaces ("nbsp")?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571648/html-tab-space-instead-of-multiple-non-breaking-spaces-nbsp)

Answer (score 0):

For a tab, you can use `&#9;` in a `<pre></pre>` tag

Comment: What about a \n tag? What's the equivalent of that?

Comment: [tab](http://www.amp-what.com/unicode/search/tab) [newline](http://www.amp-what.com/unicode/search/newline) - you can search html entities by keyword at http://www.amp-what.com/

Comment: This &#9; is also inserting a newline. How can I do without that? I need a tab to line things up without a new line.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use css to space it out.

```css
.tabbed {
  padding-left: 4em;
}
```

```html
This is a sentence up to the <span class="tabbed">tabbed part</span>
<br/>This is a bigger sentence up to the <span class="tabbed">tabbed part</span>
<br/>
```

.. but that doesn't line things up, it just puts in a gap - as shown by the two sentences of different lengths in the code snippet.

But, if you are looking for a tab solution that allows you to have multiple columns of text all lined up, you probably should use a table instead of simulating a table with tabs.