# Possible to assign tab value to html form element?

Tags: javascript, html

I am curious if it possible to assign a tab character as value to an html dropdown list. This is my current markup:

```
<select id="delimiter-select" class="form-control form-control-sm csv-select">
               <option value=",">Comma (,)</option>
               <option value=";">Semi-Colon (;)</option>
               <option value="|">Pipes (|)</option>
               <option value="Tab">Tab</option>
</select>
```

Where the value Tab is I would like that to be a tab character that I can eventually pass to JS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a tab character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9660987/how-to-get-a-tab-character)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a HTML entity for the Tab character, `&Tab;` or `&#9;`, use that:

```js
document.getElementById("delimiter-select").onchange = function (e) {console.log(` Separator is ${e.target.value} separating`)}
```

```html
<select id="delimiter-select" class="form-control form-control-sm csv-select">
  <option value=",">Comma (,)</option>
  <option value=";">Semi-Colon (;)</option>
  <option value="|">Pipes (|)</option>
  <option value="&Tab;">Tab</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It is confusing that when I look at the dom structure and only see a white space character but it sends a tab character to javascript. Any idea why it behaves this way?

Comment: @JordanRose because tab is just white space.

Comment: All HTML entities behave that way, they are just representations of the actual character, a Tab, as Cory wrote is just white space, you can't see it when it's rendered

Answer (score 0):

Use `&#9;` as the *tabulation HTML entity*

```js
console.log($('#input').val() + 'Test');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input" value="&#9;">
```