# Adding TAB to the beginning of a text string in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I've assembled the following code that creates the following text in the body of an Outlook email when run.

```
Sub InitialEvaluationWalkThru()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim strto As String, strcc As String, strbcc As String
    Dim strsub As String, strbody As String

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    strto = "first.last@me.com"
    strcc = ""
    strbcc = ""
    strsub = [$C$8] & " Update"
    strbody = "<H5>Hello Everyone,</H5>" & _
              "<H5>The Template conference rooms " & Cells(FormulaCell.Row, "C").Value & " phase is now complete!</H5>" & _
              "<H4>The overall room deployment is " & [$E$8] & "% Complete!</H4>" & _
              "<H5>Let me know if you have any questions,</H5>"

    With OutMail
        .Display
        .To = strto
        .CC = strcc
        .BCC = strbcc
        .Subject = strsub
        ' .Body = strbody
        .HTMLBody = strbody & .HTMLBody
        'You can add a file to the mail like this
        '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
        .Send 'or use .Send
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Outlook Email**

> Hello Everyone,
>
> The Template conference rooms Initial Evaluation Walk-Thru phase is
>   now complete!
>
> The overall room deployment is 0.125% Complete!
>
> Let me know if you have any questions,

**Question**

I am trying to indent the third line and have tried many different combos with no luck. I've also tried to have the cell value percentage from my sheet as 13% not 0.125%, also with no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: You can probably just toss `&tab;` or `&#9;` in front of it since it's an HTML message.

Comment: @JNevill that would be the answer =)  (`vbTab & "..."` wouldn't work, would it?)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but &#9; did nothing and &tab; resulted in a new line in the email.

Answer (score 0):

For the value, you should be able to simply multiply it by 100:

```
"<H4>The overall room deployment is " & CInt(100 * [$E$8]) & "% Complete!</H4>" &
```

`CInt` will round the value up or down. In your case it should round up 12.5 to 13.

As far as the tab, I would try what @JNevill suggests and use `&#9;` or `&emsp;` (see [Special Characters](https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/specialchars.html)) but put it in between `<pre></pre>` tags. See the many approaches discussed in this question: [How to get a tab character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9660987/how-to-get-a-tab-character).

Comment: Calculation worked - Thank You!!! I tried the <pre> tag but received Compile Error, Syntax Error. Am I not using it correctly?

<pre>&#9;</pre>"<H4>The overall room deployment is " & CInt(100 * [$E$8]) & "% Complete!</H4>" & _

Comment: Put the <pre> tags inside the double quotes (after the H4 tag)

Comment: That did the trick, but it changes my H4 heading font for some reason.

"<pre><H4>&#9;The overall room deployment is " & CInt(100 * [$E$8]) & "% Complete!</H4></pre>"

Comment: You can post that issue as a separate question and tag it as html-related. You can mark this question as answered by using the check mark to the left of the answer.